# Is it known, whether the complement of NP-hard problems is necessarily again NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, logic, complexity-classes

Neither could I find any counterexamples, nor could I show that if indeed the complement of NP-hard problems was NP-hard, one could deduce some unknown results from it, which would imply that it is indeed probably unknown.
If someone knows the answer or a paper where this question is discussed or any other reason why the answer would be known/unknown, I would be very thankful.

Comment: It would be coNP-hard, which is not known to imply NP-hardness. In particular, if a complement of an NP-complete problem is NP-hard, you have NP=coNP, which is widely considered unlikely.

Comment: @rus9384 but would we not need the information that the complement of the problem is itself also in NP to draw this conclusion? If it was NP-hard, but not NP-complete, I'm not sure about this - or did I miss something?

Comment: No, there are languages that are not in NP, coNP, are not NP-hard and are not coNP hard. E.g. the unary halting problem.

Comment: Are you claiming that the set of the complement of NPH languages is NPH to decide?